# Kafka: one consumer group consuming after another

Tags: apache-kafka, publish-subscribe

In this situation:

1 Kafka topic

Task which writes to a database uses consumer group `db_writer` - consumes events from Kafka topic and writes to database.

There's another task that wants to read from the database but only after certain events happen **and have been written to the database**. So it uses consumer group `db_reader` to wait for those events and when it sees one it should make a database read, but it doesn't know if it has been written to the database.

Is it possible for the reader task to consume from topic using `db_reader` consumer group in a way where it only gets offsets which `db_writer` has committed? That way the task can assume that the events have been written.

It's possible for the writer task to write committed events to another topic but that seems wasteful.

Comment: May be i am misunderstanding the usecase here.
The other task(db_reader one) is reading from database where is kafka consumer coming into play here?
You can have a change-data-capture flow to write to another kafka topic.
https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/data-pipelines/kafka-data-ingestion-with-cdc/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a transactional database write, then just call your reader task after the transaction finishes, or as mentioned, use CDC on your database to "read your writes"